# Having trouble retrieving data from Firebase Database in swift. Trying to figure out if its my json tree or the different ways that I am querying

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried practically everything to retrieve the entire dataset from firebase for the past day and a half. Below is my data on firebase and the code that I have tried. I've tried other queries but the one below seems to be the consensus that I've found people say to use.

```
 func firebaseDataFetch(userSearch: String) {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false) { (_) in
        self.ref = Database.database().reference()

      self.ref?.child("restaurant").observeSingleEvent(of: .value , with: { (snap) in
            guard let topArray = snap.value as? [[String:Any]] else {print(":(") ; return }
```

This is the error I receive:

FirstRoundTest[66352:4957156] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
:( which is my error handler, indicating that Im not reading the data right.

[image: Sample Image]

[image: Sample Image]

I receive error every time which is the :( in the code.

Comment: Please use Markdown to include the actual image, if you're able to (not sure if that's something you can do as a new user or not).  Also what is the error?  Please include it.  Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thanks @MaxvonHippel. You're right, since I'm a new user I don't have access to posting photos.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code to retrieve data from firebase.

```
func firebaseDataFetch(userSearch: String) {
    Database.database().reference().child("restaurant").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        print("restaurants = \(snapshot)")
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            print("restaurant = \(dict)")
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Comment: I didnt think about childadded. I thought that was for observing posts but I was wrong thanks @NikhilRavan